# Why does a CSS transition on a React component only work in one direction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions

I have 4 divs and I want to move one of them when I press the left or right arrow keys. This move should be a transition and not instantaneous, but for some reason the transition only works when I move to the left.

I thought it had something to do with the `key` prop or the divs getting unmounted, but after trying a bunch of different things I'm not sure anymore.

Please take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-grothendieck-oou90?file=/src/App.js

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score -1):

Inside Styling, you have only added  `transition:left 0.3s`. So it does not work for right. You can change it to `transition:all 0.3s`

```
.tile {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using `right` to position the tiles, only `left`, so there's no reason why that would make it work. You can try it yourself and see that it doesn't change anything.